# Reading received packets in didUpdateValueForCharacteristic

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I need to read the received bytes and parse them with a custom method, which basically goes through bytes and skips every 0x7D (or a } ). But what happens now is that it does that for only one received packet, and I dont know why that is happening since im calling my method in didUpdateValueForCharacteristic :

```
- (void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error receiving notification for characteristic %@: %@", characteristic, error);
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"Received data on a characteristic.");

    if (characteristic == self.rxCharacteristic)
    {



        self.bluetoothData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[characteristic value]];

        [self unstuff1:[characteristic value]];

        NSLog(@"First NSDAta %@", self.bluetoothData);

        [self unstuff1:self.bluetoothData];

        NSLog(@"Parsed First NSDATA %@", self.bluetoothData);

        NSString *stringForPrintingOutToConsole = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.bluetoothData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        [self.delegate didReceiveData:stringForPrintingOutToConsole];
    }
    else if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:self.class.hardwareRevisionStringUUID])
    {
        NSString *hwRevision = @"";
        const uint8_t *bytes = characteristic.value.bytes;
        for (int i = 0; i < characteristic.value.length; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"%x", bytes[i]);
            hwRevision = [hwRevision stringByAppendingFormat:@"0x%02x, ", bytes[i]];
        }

        // this one reads the hardware revision
        [self.delegate didReadHardwareRevisionString:[hwRevision substringToIndex:hwRevision.length-2]];
    }
}
```

and a custom method for parsing :

```
- (NSMutableData *)unstuff1:(NSMutableData *)mutableData {
    NSUInteger dataLength = [self.bluetoothData length];
    unsigned char *bytes = [self.bluetoothData bytes];

    uint16_t i, j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++)
    {

        if (bytes[i] == 0x7D)
        {
            bytes[j] = bytes[i+1] ^ 0x20;
            i++;
        } else
        {
            bytes[j] = bytes[i];

            j++;
        }

    }
    return mutableData;
}
```

if anyone has a clue, i'd highly appreciate help.

Comment: you never use your unstuff1 function result. you should assign in to some variable, e.g self.bluetoothData = [self unstuff1:[characteristic value]];

Comment: Correct. But I still get the same thing :/

Comment: Instead of `characteristic == self.rxCharacteristic` it might make sense to do a UUID comparison, the way you do in `else if` block.